# Django Admin: Add Action Button To Send Email

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model where Mail is a Foreign Key. The user can add a mail object,I want to add a button to the change form upon clicking which the email should be sent.

models.py

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
    ...
    mail                        = models.ForeignKey(Mail, related_name="evaluation", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I possibly want the button to execute something like this:

```
def process(self):
      if self.mail is not None:
          send_mail(
                    self.mail.subject,
                    self.mail.body,
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    [self.lead.user.email],
                    fail_silently=False
            )
```

How could I achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `actions` when defining the admin class.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

In your admin.py:

```
def send_emails(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        #call the process function defined in your Evaluation model
        obj.process()
send_emails.short_description = 'Send e-mails'


@admin.register(Evaluation)
class EvaluationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    actions = [send_emails]
```

This will give you a dropdown option to send emails to selected objects in the admin list.

The other option is to override the admin template change form and add a custom button and url for that button and handle it like any normal view.

In your admin.py:

```
@admin.register(Evaluation)
class EvaluationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'admin/evaluation_change_form.html'
    ...
```

and then in /*your base template directory*/admin/evaluation_change_form.html something like this:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block form_top %}
    <form action="{% url 'send-email' pk=original.id %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="submit" value="Send Email" name="email">. 
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Then in urls.py add a url for send-email

`url(r'^send-email/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', SendEmail.as_view(), name='send-email'),`

Then in views:

```
from django.views import View


class SendEmail(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Evaluation, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        #call the process function defined in your Evaluation model
        obj.process()
```

Comment: I tried the second option, on clicking it just tries to open another page and says "GET not allowed"

Comment: Ah, what you will want instead of an <a></a> tag is a form. Will edit answer.

Comment: When Django tells you GET is not allowed you can see that you are 90% of the way there, you are just using the wrong method to hit the URL. The view is only accepting POST (because we only defined a post function in our view), the best way to POST data is with a form, so I changed the code to use a form with method="POST" instead, and it should now work.